# Problem with Spring Boot/Hibernate while retrieving the number of recent records from MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using the following query in the userRepository to fetch the recent records which is created in the last month from MySQL

```
@Query("select count(*) from User user where user.created_on > date_add(now(), interval -1 month)")
```

But I am getting the following  errors.

```
antlr.MismatchedTokenException: expecting CLOSE, found 'month'
    at antlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211) ~[antlr-2.7.7.jar:na]

antlr.MismatchedTokenException: expecting EOF, found ')'
    at antlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211) ~[antlr-2.7.7.jar:na]
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Hi i will go against using jpql/sql query in this case. This is how i have done it. Create repository and use method `findAllByCreatedOnBetween` pass current and last month as date object, so you are basically selecting all rows between given dates.
Here is the sql generated by hibernate

Generated SQL:

```sql
select user0_.id as id1_20_, user0_.created_on as created_2_20_, user0_.name as name3_20_ from user user0_ where user0_.created_on between ? and ?
```

Entity Class `User.java`

```java
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdOn;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }
}
```

Repository

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {
    List<User> findAllByCreatedOnBetween(Date lastMonth, Date currentMonth);
}
```

Unit Test

```java
import in.silentsudo.hibernatetips.TestApplication;
import in.silentsudo.hibernatetips.domain.User;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
class UserCreatedInLastMonth {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    void testUserCreatedLastMonth() {
        User silentSudo = new User();
        silentSudo.setName("silentsudo");
        silentSudo.setCreatedOn(getCreatedDate(5, Calendar.JULY, 2019));
        userRepository.save(silentSudo);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(silentSudo.getId());

        User randomUser = new User();
        randomUser.setName("random-user");
        randomUser.setCreatedOn(getCreatedDate(1, Calendar.OCTOBER, 2020));
        userRepository.save(randomUser);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(randomUser.getId());

        //Current Calendar
        Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date today = currentCalendar.getTime();

        //A month before
        currentCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
        Date monthBefore = currentCalendar.getTime();

        Assertions.assertTrue(today.after(monthBefore));

        List<User> allUserInLastMonth = userRepository.findAllByCreatedOnBetween(monthBefore, today);
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, allUserInLastMonth.size());

    }


    private Date getCreatedDate(int day, int month, int year) {
        Calendar createdDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        createdDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        createdDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        createdDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        return createdDate.getTime();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using JPQL, since it is used by default with @Query annotation.
Enable native SQL query with:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select count(*) from User user where user.created_on > date_add(now(), interval -1 month)"
```